# Split a list into a posn in Racket

Tags: list, recursion, racket

I have this function that takes a list and a number, and it splits the list till the n element and makes it a posn, for example:

```
(split (list 1 2 3 4) 2) = (make-posn (list 1 2) (list 3 4))
(split (list 1 2 3 4) 0) = (make-posn empty (list 1 2 3 4))
(split (list empty 23) = (make-posn empty empty)
(split (list 1 2 3 4) 1) = (make-posn (list 1) (list 2 3 4))
```

The point is, i have an auxiliar function to make the first part

```
(define (aux l n)
  (cond[(empty? l) empty]
       [(zero? n) empty]
       [(positive? n) (cons (first l)(aux (rest l)(sub1 n)))]))

(aux (list 1 2 3 4) 2)) = (list 1 2)
```

But i dont know how to make the second part

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on track! You can make a second `aux2` loop to build the second portion of the output in a similar way -

```scm
(define (split l n)
  ;; left portion (your code)
  (define (aux1 l n)
    (cond
      [(empty? l) empty]
      [(zero? n) empty]
      [(positive? n)
       (cons (first l)
             (aux1 (rest l)
                   (sub1 n)))]))
  ;; right portion (new code)
  (define (aux2 l n)
    (cond
      [(empty? l) empty]
      [(zero? n) l]
      [(positive? n)
       (aux2 (cdr l)
             (sub1 n))]))
  ;; combine
  (posn (aux1 l n) (aux2 l n)))
```

Above we use `posn` which is modelled after the data structure in your question -

```scm
(struct posn (l r) #:transparent )
```

You write `split` in alternative ways. We could collapse both `aux1` and `aux2` into a single `aux` -

```scm
(define (split ls n)
  (define (aux n l r)
    (cond
      [(or (empty? r) (zero? n))
       (posn (reverse l) r)]
      [(positive? n)
       (aux (sub1 n)
            (cons (car r) l)
            (cdr r))]
      [else
       (error 'split "cannot split using a negative number")]))
  (aux n empty ls))
```

Or we could write `aux` using continuation-passing style -

```scm
(define (split t n)
  (define (aux t n return)
    (cond
      [(or (empty? t) (zero? n))
       (return empty t)]
      [(positive? n)
       (aux (cdr t)
            (sub1 n)
            (lambda (l r)
              (return (cons (car t) l) r)))]
      [else
       (error 'split "cannot split using a negative number")]))
  (aux t n posn))
```

Using the examples from your question -

```scm
(split (list 1 2 3 4) 2)
(split (list 1 2 3 4) 0)
(split empty 23)
(split (list 1 2 3 4) 1)
```

Each implementation of `split` above produces the same output -

```scm
(posn '(1 2) '(3 4))
(posn '() '(1 2 3 4))
(posn '() '())
(posn '(1) '(2 3 4))
```